# What cause Unexpted token }?

Tags: javascript, php

can some tell me please what is issue here that throw:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

The issue code:

```
        $url = '<a href="#" onClick="convertVidToMp3("'.$searchResult['id']['videoId'].','.$searchResult['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'].','.htmlentities($searchResult['snippet']['title']).'");" rel="loadpage">';
```

Its all about this line,because when i click on that link its should active some test script:

```
function convertVidToMp3(id, thumb, title) {

alert('hello');

return false;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: The error must be somewhere else as the given JavaScript above is 100% valid.

Comment: Google is my best friend.When i need help is when i nearly tried everything. @iidmean its not other script or line because when delete this i dont have error on click..

Comment: The quotes in `$url` don't make sense... `<a href="#" onClick="convertVidToMp3("videoId,thumbnail,title");" rel="loadpage">`

Comment: Yea i now see what i did wrong thanks to RamRaider.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The use of quotes was wrong, try the following. By assigning the values as variables first it is much easier to see potential issues when dealing with quotes / mismatched quotes (IMHO anyway)

```
$id=$searchResult['id']['videoId'];
$thumb=$searchResult['snippet']['thumbnails']['default']['url'];
$title=htmlentities( $searchResult['snippet']['title'] );

$url = '<a href="#" onclick=\'convertVidToMp3( "'.$id.'", "'.$thumb.'", "'.$title.'");\' rel="loadpage">';
```

Comment: Wow you just save my life! this did work thanks dude!

Comment: no problem. btw - you need some content for the link and a closing tag but I guess you already know that

Comment: *"The use of quotes was wrong"* - I had a feeling about that earlier, *way to go* ;-)